# I want to check if 4 Conditions are meet something should happen

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, if-statement

i am still new to c# i am trying to write a code that would check my if condition if 4 conditions are met then something happens.
Here is my codes:`enter code here`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;
public class NameTrans : MonoBehaviour {
    public string thename;
    public GameObject inputField;
    public GameObject textDisplay;
    public GameObject textDisplay2;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Showname () {
        thename = inputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;
     if (thename.ToUpper().Contains("Man".ToUpper()) || thename.ToUpper().Contains("Dog".ToUpper()))
        {

            textDisplay2.SetActive(false);
            textDisplay.SetActive(true);
            textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "WOrks" ;
        }
       else
        {
            textDisplay.SetActive(false);
            textDisplay2.SetActive(true);
            textDisplay2.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Not WORK" ;
        }

            }


}
```

Comment: Your if statement curently contains two conditions.What are the four conditions that should be met? 
Can you share your Unity project, or show us what objects you have in Unity's user interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case only one of 4 conditions needs to be met, you are already doing the right thing. You just need to add the missing two condidions.

```
if((thename.ToUpper().Contains("Man".ToUpper())) || 
   (thename.ToUpper().Contains("Dog".ToUpper())) ||
   (thename.ToUpper().Contains("Cat".ToUpper())) ||       
   (thename.ToUpper().Contains("Fish".ToUpper())))
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

If all 4 conditions need to be met, you need to connect the conditions with "&&" instead of "||".

```
if((thename.ToUpper().Contains("Man".ToUpper())) && 
   (thename.ToUpper().Contains("Dog".ToUpper())) &&
   (thename.ToUpper().Contains("Cat".ToUpper())) &&       
   (thename.ToUpper().Contains("Fish".ToUpper())))
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

**UPDATE with new info**
If you want to check if any 4 of x conditions are true, I would probably do something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;
public class NameTrans : MonoBehaviour {
    public string thename;
    public GameObject inputField;
    public GameObject textDisplay;
    public GameObject textDisplay2;
    private string[] conditions;
    private int counter;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Showname () {
     thename = inputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;
     conditions = {"Man", "Dog", "Cat", "Fish", "Goat", 
                   "Frog", "Bird", "Alligator"};
     counter = 0;

     foreach(string cond in conditions)
     {
         if (thename.ToUpper().Contains(cond.ToUpper())
         {
             counter += 1;
             if (counter >= 4)
             {
                 break;   
             }
         }
     }

     if (counter >= 4)
        {

            textDisplay2.SetActive(false);
            textDisplay.SetActive(true);
            textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "WOrks" ;
        }
       else
        {
            textDisplay.SetActive(false);
            textDisplay2.SetActive(true);
            textDisplay2.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Not WORK" ;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, okay thanks for your answer. If i have more than man or Dog or cat or fish  or 20 more words. and i want it to check when either of the 4 condition is true some should happen

Comment: Because with your answer if cat is not available

Comment: it Will give a false Response.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly? Do you have more than 4 conditions? Do you want your if-block to execute if 4 out of those X conditions are met?

Comment: Yes i have more than 4 conditions. and i want that if any of the 4 out of let say 8 is True something should happen.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the new information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot `enter code here *Paddex* for the answer.
For those using unity Add New string[]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public string thename;
    public GameObject inputField;
    public GameObject textDisplay;
    public GameObject textDisplay2;
    private string[] conditions;
    private int counter;
    // Use this for initialization

    public void Showname()
    {
        thename = inputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;
        conditions = new string[] {
            "Man", "Dog", "Cat", "Fish", "Goat", 
                   "Frog", "Bird", "Alligator"};
        counter = 0;
        foreach (string cond in conditions)
        {
            if (thename.ToUpper().Contains(cond.ToUpper()))
            {
                counter += 1;
                if (counter >= 4)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (counter >= 4)
        {

            textDisplay2.SetActive(false);
            textDisplay.SetActive(true);
            textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "WOrks";
        }
        else
        {
            textDisplay.SetActive(false);
            textDisplay2.SetActive(true);
            textDisplay2.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Not WORK";
        }

    }


}
```